# "Cannot find the object [stored proc] because it does not exist or you do not have permissions", when it definitely does exist and have permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a stored procedure (below) that definitely exists and I am trying to execute it as a user which definitely has permissions. I checked this more times than was necessary. But I still get the following error

> Cannot find the object [stored proc] because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

I found that if I removed permissions, than I got a more accurate message stating that I did not have execute permissions.

I tried scripting the stored procedure and giving it a different name, but this didn't help either.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Child_Get] 
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [tblChilds] WHERE [ID] = @ID
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[Child_Get] to 'BLAH\NT4Name'
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

This was very weird, but the problem was the "GRANT EXECUTE ..." statement after the stored procedure. After I removed this line everything worked fine.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Child_Get] @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [tblChilds] WHERE [ID] = @ID
END
GO
```

I imagine that the "GRANT EXECUTE ...." somehow magically gets included in the stored proc (despite being outside of the BEGIN / END and after a GO). This means that some users have permissions defined to execute the sproc, but do not have enough permissions to "GRANT EXECUTE ...", and this leads to the very misleading ***"Cannot find the object [storedproc] because it does not exist or you do not have permissions"*** error message.

Comment: We made the same error. Discovered it by looking at the created script from SQL Server Management Studio for the stored procedure - which included the GRANT statements after procedure's END

Comment: Found that I was missing the 'GO' between the end of procedure and before the `EXECUTE GRANT...` statement.